# Google 64-bit requirement only works for some apps

Tags: android, android-layout

For some reason my app is not 64-bit compatible.

My first thought was that it my be the lib files. I checked the resulting apk: I have arm64-v8a, armeabi, armebi-v7a, mips, x86 which all contain the same-named .so files. So, I'm thinking it is maybe because x86_64 is missing? But, I have another project running the exact same libs which IS 64-bit compatible according to the play dashboard. I can't see any difference between the two lib or gradle setups.

Has anyone encountered something similar?

UPDATE: Here is the resulting libs from analizing the apk: 
[image]

Like I stated above, there are .so files for all except x86_64. Could this be the issue? Do you HAVE to have .so files for both arm64-v8a AND x86_64? And why would this not be an issue for my other projects?

Another Update: 
Ok, so I THINK its not working cause I have x86 and not x86_64. Docs say " It isn't required to support every 64-bit architecture, but for each native 32-bit architecture you support you must include the corresponding 64-bit architecture." ... does this mean I can just remove x86 and it should work fine? Also, is it a good idea to remove x86? Does it remove support for many devices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I figured it out.

It seems that I managed to 'trick' google into thinking my apps were 64-bit compatible. Just because the x86_64 FOLDER was available, I guess the google console assumed it contained the required libraries. The problem was that the x86_64 libs were missing. My solution, though not ideal, was to remove the x86 libraries (small percentage of device support anyway) so that I don't need x86_64.

SO, yay :) all my apps are now 64-bit compliant (although I've lost SOME device support).

Answer (score 0):

as described in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit)

you should add ndk.abiFilters :

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

to you app build.gradle file

Comment: Hey Rob! Thanks, but I'm not using ndk, I'm just using .so libraries (sorry if I'm still incorrect, as I am still learning about all this). And, my other project also uses these .so libraries and does NOT have this in the gradle file (and seems to be compatible).

Comment: Did you publish your other app after 1 of August ? There was updated privacy policy in google development console.

May be your libraries used ndk, you can check that from the link that I have shared(https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#apk-analyzer), you can analyze apk, to see which ndk folders are missing in your app.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi Rob! Thank you again for your time! I did analyze the APK. Updated the question to reflect this.